# Implicit cast on Action

Tags: .net, delegates, casting

I'm using a third party library class that has the following (abbreviated) method:

```
public void DoSomethingAsync(Action<ResultInfo> callback)
```

Rather than have a reference to this third party library in my application code project, I've created a wrapper class that abstracts the third party dependencies.  So, what I'm trying to do is have a wrapper method that looks like the following:

```
public void MyDoSomethingAsync(Action<MyResultInfo> callback)
{
    this.wrappedClass.DoSomethingAsync(callback);
}
```

The problem is that I need to convert the `callback` parameter from `Action<MyResultInfo>` to `Action<ResultInfo>`.  Is this possible with a custom implicit cast operator or is there an alternative approach that someone can recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you wouldn't be able to do so directly, even if `MyResultInfo` derived from `ResultInfo`; [delegate contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) wouldn't apply here as the `Action<MyResultInfo>` wouldn't be able to handle any instance derived from `ResultInfo` (so that disqualifies an `Action<MyResultInfo>` from being used in place of an `Action<ResultInfo>`)

However, that doesn't mean you can't use an adapter, like so:

```
public void MyDoSomethingAsync(Action<MyResultInfo> callback)
{
    // Create the action which will transform ResultInfo
    // into MyResultInfo and then pass to the wrapped
    // class.
    // Create the action first.
    Action<ResultInfo> a = ri => {
        // Translate ri into MyResultInfo.
        MyResultInfo mri = (translate here);

        // Call the callback with the translated result.
        callback(mri);
    };

    // Pass the action to the wrapped class.
    this.wrappedClass.DoSomethingAsync(a);
}
```

Comment: I tend to disagree with first statement, because contravariance with delegates works just in opposite, `Action<Base>` can be cast to `Action<Derived>`

Comment: Second thing is that you link points to non-generic delegate contravariance, that doesn't work for `Action<T>`, generic delegate contravariance was introduced only in .net 4.0.

Comment: now I totally agree with your answer. But I still really thing that it is design flaw in the question itself. It is been asked how to make *wrong* thing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that what you want to make may result in inconsistency. I assume that `MyResultInfo` is derived from `ResultInfo` because otherwise it doesn't make any sense.

Now back to inconsistency. Imagine that you have delegate `Action<ResultInfo> callback`. Calling code could call it like this: `callback(new MyResultInfo());` and call your `Action<MyResultInfo>` and it will work fine. But imagine it is called like this: `callback(new ResultInfo());`, `Action<ResultInfo>` allows it, but it will produce exception because `ResultInfo` can't be cast to `MyResultInfo`.